# Losing formatting after pasting code into a Gist

Tags: javascript, gist

I realize I can append some sort of querystring to a gist url to set tab spacing but that sucks.  Is there some way to retain the spacing period without having to do that?

Example:

[image: cirpt]

Comment: change from using tabs to spaces. what are you using? is that vs-code?

Comment: no intellij but if I change from tab to spaces can I still use tab?

Comment: I have the same issue regardless of whether I use tabs or spaces